# Iphone SDK, как можно закастомайзить UIPIckerView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone

Есть `UIPickerView` стандартный, 1 штука. Требуется создать `UIPickerView` с картинками и с `UILabel`, в которые я буду выводить своим шрифтом разные данные. Какие есть идеи?

Comment: Все оказалось очень просто, как сделал расскажу и поделюсь чуть позже когда все отлажу и пофиксю баги!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле .h создаем наш пикер, так как мы будем его релизить, то делаем его глобальным **`UIPickerView *ourPicker;`**, пока на .h файл можно сохранить и перейти в .m файл. Тут мы инициализируем наш пикер:

```
ourPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 215.0f, 320.0f, 100.0f)];
ourPicker.delegate = self;
ourPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:ourPicker];
```

Запускаем и видим пустой пикер :)
Создаем массив, в котором будут храниться изображения для пикера `NSMutableArray *imageArray;`, в м файле инициализируем его и забиваем картинками

```
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[imageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img1"]];
[imageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img2"]];
[imageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img3"]];
[imageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img4"]];
[imageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img5"]];
[imageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img6"]];
```

И так, массив создан и заполнен картинками, формат картинок не указываю, укажу позже. Потом нам нужен массив для отображения информации в наших метках, делаем то же самое:

```
arrayOfLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[arrayOfLabels addObject:@"description1"];
[arrayOfLabels addObject:@"description2"];
[arrayOfLabels addObject:@"description3"];
[arrayOfLabels addObject:@"description4"];
[arrayOfLabels addObject:@"description5"];
[arrayOfLabels addObject:@"description6"];`
```

И это мы тоже создали не так трудно, теперь самое главное.
Для отображения всего этого хаоса нам нужен всего один делегейт метод пикервью(); Вот он:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {}
```

Внутри фигурных скобок пишем это:

```
UILabel *ourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; // вот она наша меточка;
ourLabel.frame = CGRectMake(-30, -40, 80, 80); // позиция меточки;
[ourLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft]; // выравнивание текста внутри метки;
[ourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10]]; 
ourLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[ourLabel setText:[arrayOfLabels objectAtIndex:row]]; // расставляем меточки строго по "строкам"
[ourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0]];
UIImage *check = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[imageArray objectAtIndex:row]]];  // ну тут все по аналогии
checkView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:check];
checkView.frame = CGRectMake(-65, -10, 30, 20);
[checkView addSubview:ourLabel];
customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [customView addSubview:ourLabel];
//NSLog(@"Selected Value %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]);
//if(selectedRowInPicker == row){}
    [customView addSubview:checkView];
return customView;
return [arrayOfLabels objectAtIndex:row];`
```

Не забываем, что массивы все инициализируются в методе `ViewDidLoad{}`, и на последок, если у вас дофига картинок, то не стоит их забивать таким хардкорным методом, забить их в массив можно будет и простым циклом :) Ну вот если я ничего не напутал, то все должно работать как надо. Не забывайте релизнуть массивы в методе `- (void)dealloc{}`. Возникнут проблемы, задавайте вопросы (часть материала была взята с сайта stackoverflow).

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста все ваши комментарии в отдельный ответ. По теме: по сути, UIPickerView - это тот же UITableView (хотя он и не наследуется от него явно). Так что да, способ задания содержимого ячеек тот же, вы все правильно расписали.

Comment: Ну вроде оформил как надо.